# List of greetings phrases in english for NLP task?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, deep-learning, chatbot

I want lists of greetings phrases in English for natural language processing tasks, so I wonder where can I find something like that ?

Comment: https://github.com/niderhoff/nlp-datasets

Comment: make an agent on dialogflow, enable small-talk, and get the greeting phrases from utterances of `smalltalk.greetings.hello`

Answer (score 6):

Hopefully it helps!

> ["hi", "hello", "hey", "helloo", "hellooo", "g morining",  "gmorning",  "good morning", "morning", "good day", "good afternoon", "good evening", "greetings", "greeting", "good to see you", "its good seeing you", "how are you", "how're you", "how are you doing", "how ya doin'", "how ya doin", "how is everything", "how is everything going", "how's everything going", "how is you", "how's you", "how are things", "how're things", "how is it going", "how's it going", "how's it goin'", "how's it goin", "how is life been treating you", "how's life been treating you", "how have you been", "how've you been", "what is up", "what's up", "what is cracking", "what's cracking", "what is good", "what's good", "what is happening", "what's happening", "what is new", "what's new", "what is neww", "g’day", "howdy"]

Save this as a txt file and load it later.

```
import json
greeting_words = json.loads(open('greetings.txt', 'r').read())
print(greeting_words)

>> ["hi", "hello", "hey", "helloo", "hellooo", "g morining",  "gmorning",  "good morning", "morning", "good day", "good afternoon", "good evening", "greetings", "greeting", "good to see you", "its good seeing you", "how are you", "how're you", "how are you doing", "how ya doin'", "how ya doin", "how is everything", "how is everything going", "how's everything going", "how is you", "how's you", "how are things", "how're things", "how is it going", "how's it going", "how's it goin'", "how's it goin", "how is life been treating you", "how's life been treating you", "how have you been", "how've you been", "what is up", "what's up", "what is cracking", "what's cracking", "what is good", "what's good", "what is happening", "what's happening", "what is new", "what's new", "what is neww", "g’day", "howdy"]
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can find a premade list of greeting phrases. However, there are certain websites where you can scrape data from and generate a list of phrases and then use it for your NLP task.

Example Websites:

1. https://www.fluentu.com/blog/english/basic-english-phrases/
2. https://reallifeglobal.com/23-different-ways-greet-someone-english/

Just google and you'd find plenty of useful links. Write a quick parser in Python and get your work done.